# Turn off google contacts sync in Redmi Note 5 Pro

Tags: sync, xiaomi, google-contacts, redmi

I have multiple accounts in my redmi note 5 pro and the contact names are getting changed due to same contacts in multiple accounts. I want to stop syncing contacts in one of them. How do I do so?

Comment: I don't use multiple Google accounts but when I open Android Settings -> Accounts -> Google account x -> Accountsynchronization I can specify what should be synced. This should allow you to disable contacs sync selectively on some Google accounts.